# Continuous or Discrete Sample Data?

Tags: probability, distributions

I am currently trying to estimate stock levels in a monte carlo simulation, i have certain integer sample data for product A,B,C with each having a sample size of 100. When trying to do a fit to a type of distribution, what should be the data type of sample data - continuous or discrete?

Edit:

I am trying to model the demand pattern of 75 SKUS and estimate what should be the inventory levels be at the production line. The SKUs are are split into Five categories A,B,C,D,E. For categories C,D,E- distribution type are exponential for C(beta = 3) and poisson for D and E (Lambda = 1 for D and Lambda =0.5 for E). For A and B, i have 5 separate data sets of sample demand data for each SKU, i need to decide what distribution do they follow, and for that i need to select what kind of data type are the sample datasets - continuous or discrete before deciding the fit. The sample data sets are historic demands of each product over a period of 100 days. hope this gives more clarity

Comment: Welcome to CV, Saathvik.  Could you please explain (by editing your question) what you mean by "sample data" and tell us what they measure?  Note, too, that the question of continuous vs. discrete is partly a matter of your analytical objectives: it's not always answerable solely by considering the type of data.

Comment: Hi @whuber , i have edited the question